# How to create a Table-Like Reliable Collection

Tags: azure-service-fabric

What is the best way to create a table-like reliable collection? Can we role out our own?

I am looking for something to store simple lists or bags for indexes and to track keys and other simple details since the cost of enumerating multi-partition dictionaries is so high.  Preferably sequential rather than random access.

The obvious options:

1. IDictionary `<Guid, List>` has concurrency issues and poor performance
2. Try to enumerate a queue but I doubt it will be better than dictionary
3. Use an external data store

None of these seem particularly good.

Comment: Do you have an example usage. There are queues and dictionaries that solve 80% of situations. What challenge do you have?

Comment: List<string> or Collection<String>  is my data .. . Such data is  very common .

Comment: Can these be stored on a per partition basis? from your comment below as though this is reference data and needs to be used in each partition. If this is the case, can you just load it up on service start and use from then on.

Comment: Yes the plan is to use them on service start but the data does change .. I can certainly duplicate on each partition . This is a pretty common scenario look at any DB and about 2/3 of the tables will be small table , rarely changed ( but they do change) . The obvious answer is to use Azure Table / SQL for this data but i was hoping if there is an effective SF  eg a ReliableCollection<string>

Comment: Your best bet may be to have another service - possibly a stateless service running on every node. On startup this service connects to the external store to get the reference data and then makes it available through an api. In this way the data is stored locally on each system in memory and available through a local call from your processing partitions.

Comment: @Nick Randell yes i think an external store is the best way at present though it is a significant limitation eg your indexes / reference data  may be in another data store with different backups etc.

Answer (score 1):

The partitioning is actually to gain performance. The trick is to shard your data in such a way that cross partition queries aren't needed. You can also create multiple dictionaries with different aggregates of the same data. (use transactions)

Read more in the chapter 'plan for partitioning' [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning/).

Comment: Not sure if partitioning comes  into this the data is a string[] , I can certainly partition it but 70% of calls will be getAll , and 10% will do a sequential scan. Think of Colours , a Dictionary , Index , Hashset etc etc . The service also has a massive dictionary but needs such reference data to do its work.,

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can roll out your own reliable collection. After all, a reliable collection is just a in-memory data structure backed by a Azure Storage object. If you want a reliable list of string, you can implement `IList<string>`, and in the various methods (add, remove, getEnumerator, ecc.) insert code to track, persist the data structure.

Based on your content, it can be a table (if you can generate a good partition/row key), or just a blob (and you serialize/deserialize the content each time, or at checkpoints, or... your policy!)

I did not get why `IReliableDictionary<K, V>` is not good for you. Do you need to store key, value pairs, and you do not want keys to be distributed in partitions, for performance reasons? (Because a "getAll" will spawn machines?)

Or do you need just a list of keys (like colors, or like you have in an HashSet?).

In any case, depending on the size of data, you can partition them differently, using something like IReliableDictionary, where the int can be just one (like "42", and you'll have one partition), or a few (hash and then mod (%) the number you want), and you will get a whole bunch of keys (from every key to N sections of keys) at once.

Comment: I think You need to role your own but their are no real examples .. and its a bit tricky as you will need to replicate the changes.

Comment: Yes Hashset / colours is the main thing im using now but a table is also useful  Im using Reliable dictionary now but its pretty ugly / slow  when doing a sequential scan eg IAsyncEnumerable over paritions..  One of the main uses for this is an index for the main collection so you dont need to do an Ienumerable iteration. .